# Trigger on MySQL tables with variable?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create in MySQL trigger on such schema:

## mail

- oid id
- varchar name
- varchar reference

## adress_mail

- oid id
- oid id_mail
- oid id_adress

## adress

- oid id
- varchar name

after something is inserted into adress_mail it is updating 'mail.reference' with value like every 'adress.name' for example:

I am inserting adress_mail with (1,5,6) and (1,5,7) so trigger will update 'mail.reference' with values from 'adress.name where adress.id = 6' and 'adress.name where adress.id = 7'

> Q: The whole problem is how to loop on adress_mail table and get all
> 'adress.name' in 1 varchar and then just update 'mail.reference' with
> that value?

I can setup something like var (variable) in trigger and then collect all results from select?

PS 'mail.reference' it's varchar row to improve some searching feature of application, because I don't have possibility to loop on 'adress_mail' table.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't do that ! You are using an sql data base, and the main idea of it is table relations, so when you'll have to look for data from address linked to mail, perform a select with joins on address_mail.

Comment: Well I perform a select command with join, but that is join with about 30k of records, for each row its about 5 - 6 joins. 

My issue is connected with filtering and it took about 20 sec to gerenate result of procedure that will return me 25k rows with joins. (server is not best performance machine)

So now I have 'select with joins' and it's working hardly too slow. So adding additional column with mail.reference will support one small function in my application.